# Select2 - start ajax search on enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I have a Select2 input which I use to search (remote data).
Currently, it works like this:

when user types 1 one more characters we trigger search automatically

**Now, the fun part:**

I need to add following behaviour:

when user focus on in this input and just hits Enter button, I need to trigger search with one character '*' BUT without actually writing that character in the input.

It should just send search request with character * but input should stay empty.

Is that even possible without messing Select2 code?

My code:

```
$("#account").select2({
    language: "en",
    ajax: {
        url: window.urls.ajax_account_search,
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 500,
        data: function(params){
            console.log(params);
            return {
                query: params.term,
                page: params.page
            }
        },
        processResults: function(data, params){
            return {
                results: data.items
            }
        },
        cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; },
    templateResult: formatSearchResult,
    templateSelection: formatSearchSelection,
    minimumInputLength: 1
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30517128/how-to-programmatically-inject-search-queries-into-select2-v4

Comment: Thanks for the link but it doesn't fit my case. Using method from your link character "*" will be displayed in the input.

Comment: There is a method `open` that detects open event.

Comment: How may it be useful in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of triggering the search on enter (with `*` being sent), you can just send `*` when there is no search term present. This also means dropping the `minimumInputLength` requirement, but that seems to line up with what you are looking for.

```
$("#account").select2({
    language: "en",
    ajax: {
        url: window.urls.ajax_account_search,
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 500,
        data: function(params){
            return {
                query: params.term || '*', // send * if there is no term
                page: params.page
            }
        },
        processResults: function(data, params){
            return {
                results: data.items
            }
        },
        cache: true
    },
    escapeMarkup: function(m) { return m; },
    templateResult: formatSearchResult,
    templateSelection: formatSearchSelection
});
```