# Select2 with ajax - issue with selecting values

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using Select2 plugin as below:

**JS**

```
function initAssignmentsAjax() {

        $("#assignments").empty();

        $( "#assignments" ).select2( {
            placeholder: "Select an assignment",
            allowClear: true,

            ajax: {
                url: "/Home/GetAssignments",
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                data: function ( params ) {
                    return {
                        q: params.term, // search term
                        page: params.page
                    };
                },

                processResults: processAssignmentsResult,

                cache: true
            },
            escapeMarkup: function ( markup ) { return markup; }, // let our custom formatter work    TUTAJ WCHODZI PO assignmentsTemplateSelectionHandler
            minimumInputLength: 3, //1
            templateSelection: assignmentsTemplateSelectionHandler,
            templateResult: assignmentsTemplateResultHandler
        } )
    }

    function processAssignmentsResult(data, params) {

        var json = JSON.parse( data.Data );
        var x = $.map( json, function ( item ) {
            return {
                text: item.ProjectNumber + ' : ' + item.BatchName,
                children: item.ChildItems,
            };
        } )

        return { results: x };
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="assignments" style="width: 500px;" ></select>
```

It works fine when I am typing values from UI - it sends Ajax query to controller and on the end presents values in control.

I have added also below function ( based on [How to programmatically inject search queries into Select2 v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30517128/how-to-programmatically-inject-search-queries-into-select2-v4#30552284) ) to programaticly enter value to search

```
function selectAssignments( term ) {

    $( "#assignments" ).empty();

    var assignmentElementControl = $( "#assignments" );

    assignmentElementControl.select2( 'open' );

    // Get the search box within the dropdown or the selection
    // Dropdown = single, Selection = multiple
    var $search = assignmentElementControl.data( 'select2' ).dropdown.$search || assignmentElementControl.data( 'select2' ).selection.$search;
    // This is undocumented and may change in the future

    $search.val( term );
    $search.trigger( 'keyup' );
}
```

When I reload page and using this function from browser console ( or bind it to some button in UI ) it also works fine.
But it stop to work when I first try to search by typing in Select2 control ( this pass ) but then when I try to use this function it does not run ajax search query from Select2 control ( it open searching list, show entered query, but not fire ajax ). So what using Select2 UI searching break this function to work ?

Answer (score 0):

In your function `selectAssignments()` try to trigger the `change` of the `select2`:

```
$search.val( term );
$search.trigger( 'keyup' );
$search.trigger( 'change' ); //Here
```

Comment: I was trying before - not help. But thanks for reply